# Best way to see if a number is a "real" number (int/float) or a string ("1"/"1.2")

Tags: php, numbers

I have a function that is called over and over from my code where I can pass a variable and the function acts differently if the parameter is a "real" (int/float) number (in other words does not do any manipulation nor add the quotes around it when passed to a MySQL query).  Currently my code does a double type check, but is there a better way ?

```
$a = 1;
$b = '1';
$is_num = (is_numeric($a) && !is_string($a)); //true
$is_num = (is_numeric($b) && !is_string($b)); //false
```

is there a better faster way to do this ?

for example (VERY simplified version):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ';
$field = 'id';
$operator = '=';
$value = 2;

$query .= '`'.$field.'`'.$operator;
$is_num = (is_numeric($value) && !is_string($value));
if($is_num){
    $query .=$value;
}else{
    $query .='"'.mysql_real_escape_string((string)$value).'"';
}
$query .=';';
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly what your desired behavior is? Are you just trying to do an `if-then` where if it's a string it does one thing, and another if it's an int?

Comment: Why not just force it to be a number if you need it to be? (Or a string, if that's preferred?)

Comment: is a query builder, if you pass a string (even a number-string) should add the quotes to it, if you pass a real number, not.  This to allow the person that build the query to cast or not the values, for example a query with `field="1"` is different from a query with `field=1` depending on the type of `field`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your number is always an integer, then you can use [`is_int`](http://php.net/is_int).  If there is a possibility that it might be a decimal-point number and you want that to return `$is_num == true` then no, you have to do the check as you are or check either type with `is_int($a) || is_float($a)`

The specific purpose of [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) is to check if it is "numeric or a numeric string" and there is no "all number types" catch-all.

However, given your comment that this is for a query builder, why not just add quotes if `is_string` and not otherwise?

Comment: There is other manipulation applied to other than the query, my example was just simple.  I just need to know what is the best way to do a "type" check without having to cast or apply functions twice

Answer (score 1):

If you're just dealing with integers, `is_int($a)` works. If you're dealing with floats too, use

```
is_int($a) || is_float($a)
```

Comment: trying to do it with just one function call

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_number($input)
{
    if ( ! is_int($input) AND is_numeric($input))
    {
        return (float) $input === $input;
    }
    else
    {
        return (int) $input === $input;
    }
}

echo is_number('1.23')? 'true': 'false'; # false
echo is_number(1.23)? 'true': 'false'; # true
echo is_number(1)? 'true': 'false'; # true
echo is_number('1')? 'true': 'false'; # false
```

It is better to cast to string, because SQL will cast to int/float if that is the field type.

Comment: I believe you can do the same with `return (is_numeric($input) && !is_string($input));`

Comment: You do not want to cast ALWAYS as you would lose the benefits of the indexes. Plus sometime you might want to cast to integer.